# how to SELECT with left join where count of one table is more than 1?

Tags: laravel

I have implemented a query like this :

```
$categories = DB::select("SELECT categories.* FROM categories left JOIN products on products.category_root = categories.id")
                ->withCount('products')
                ->where('products_count' , '>' , 0)->get();
```

that mean get categories where have at least one product with category_root equal the `category->id`

my products table have 3 column with names : `category_root` , `category_parent` , `category_id`
and I want to check each of them in my collections.

how to get not empty categories ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$categories = Category::whereExists(function ($query){
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))->from('products')->whereRaw('products.category_root = categories.id');
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `leftJoin()` method, You can add your condition in the closure:

```php
$categories = DB::table('categories')
                ->leftJoin('products', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('categories.id', '=', 'products.category_root')
                         ->orWhere('categories.id', '=', 'products.category_parent')
                         ->orWhere('categories.id', '=', 'products.category_id');
                })
                ->select('categories.*')
                ->whereNotNull('products.id')
                ->withCount('products')
                ->get();
```